# Why am I getting 4x transfer speeds using SMB to NAS RAID when compared to the very poor FTP rate?

Tags: raid, ftp, nas, smb, buffalo-nas

When transferring any size or amount of files to NAS RAID via FTP the transfer rate is abysmally slow at 3MB/s. When I transfer same files across a SMBv1 connection I can achieve 11.3MB/s. Given the below specs, I cannot reconcile 3MB/s transfer speeds as it would take over 2 weeks to finish a tiny 500GB transfer.

- **Source Desktop**: Windows 10 w/ 16GB RAM & Core i7 @ 3.40GHz w/ [Intel 82579LM NIC](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/47620/intel-82579lm-gigabit-ethernet-phy/specifications.html)
  Rated for **1 Gigabit**
- **Source Drive**: WD 5400RPM HDD Connected and Rated for SATAIII **6.0Gb/s**
- **Network**: Source/Destination Connected via Cat6 Ethernet to [Asus RT-AC1200](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking-IoT-Servers/WiFi-Routers/ASUS-WiFi-Routers/RT-AC1200-V2/techspec/) Router
  Rated for **100Mbps**
- **Destination RAID**: [Buffalo TS-XLC66](http://www.buffalo-asia.com/forbusiness/business_nas/ts3/ts-xl_r5-ap/) w/ RAID 10 - Rated for **100Mbps** 
  (Latest Firmware v1.76 released as of 2.14.2022)
- **Destination Drives** 4x WD 2TB 5400RPM HDDs

I have tried/diagnosed the following with no change:

- FileZilla: Transferring <10MB or 4GB files tops outs at 3MB/s, even.
- CyberDuck: Transferring <10MB or 4GB files tops out at 5.1MB/s.
- SMBv1: Transferring <50MB or 4GB files achieves 11.3MB/s
- Different Router: [Asus TM-AC1900](https://www.newegg.com/asus-tm-ac1900-ieee-802-11a-b-g-n-ac-ipv4-ipv6/p/0E6-00CN-00005) (Rated for 1 Gigabit) -  maxes out FTP transfer at 3MB/s
- Different RAID (same HDDs): Buffalo TS-X4.0TL/R5 - maxes out FTP transfer at 3MB/s
- Different Cat 6 Cables (<10ft btw)
- Removed all traffic on network to only FTP/SMB connection between Source and Destination.
- All HDDs in question have 'Good' SMART results individually tested via Speccy and CrystalDiskInfo
- Transferring files via FTP to a different destination device (SBC) produces 10MB/s+ speeds.
- Tried to research this particular issue but cannot find exact fit. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1153761/increase-nas-transfer-speeds) question/issue comes close but isn't the same
- Disabling Windows Firewall
- FTP transfer from command line in both Active and Passive Mode.
- The OS and all drivers and devices have been checked and rechecked for updates.

Given the information and diagnostics above my understanding is that the bottleneck is likely the RAID. However, I also suspect it may be software since different FTP softwares produce different maxes. 3MB/s is horrifically low even taking into consideration the CPU of the RAID and [2x reduction](https://www.bing.com/search?q=RAID%20speed%20RAID%2010&cvid=e0a54c6c76624664b9a38319870f2bc4&aqs=edge..69i57j0l3j69i60.3599j0j3&FORM=ANAB01&PC=U531) of HDD write speed when using RAID 10. Especially if the device proves to be capable of writing at least 11MB/s.

Why are FTP transfer rates so slow overall? Why are SMBv1 speeds 4x greater than FTP?

Here is a screenshot of `top` and `vmstat` while transferring 500MB file via FTP at 3MB/s.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Check if you have se on computer NIC kind of QoS. Check the speed with commandline `ftp` program. Try to stop Windows firewall and check again

Comment: Are the client and server on yje same LAN (and in tje same subnet)?  If so the router should be irrelevant.  If not, part of the problem could be NAT. (FTP is a horrible protocol).  Does it make a difference if, for FTP, you use active or passive mode?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov. Any QOS on router and Win 10 is confirmed to be disabled. There is no extra QOS software installed. MS Defender, Domain, Private/Public Firewalls were turned off and FTP transfer from command line has same results. ie: .98GB sent in 270.51sec @ 3633.85 KB/s.

Comment: @davidgo Yes. Client and Server are on same LAN and subnet. Mentioned rates were in default passive mode. Upon changing to Active mode, rate was reduced to 1.6MB/s

Comment: It can be the ftp server of the NAS. Try with some public ftp servers.

Comment: This problem is almost certainly with the NAS software.  Looking at the specs it is pretty old and not very powerful.  (ie its not the router. Its also not the RAID level).  Are you able to work out what FTP server the NAS is running?  (Telnetting to it on port 21 could give you a welcome banner telling you the version)

Comment: I understand that the NAS is far from the latest and greatest but it is still rated for 100MB/s. Should I honestly expect decrease in performance despite support still being provided as of 5 months ago? That seems like saying an SSD would write slower simply due to age (despite having no degradation) or that the NAS, at peak performance out of the box, only ever transferred at 3MB rate.

Unfortunately telnet does not produce FTP version. `ftp MYIP 21` -> `220 MYIP FTP server ready`

Comment: (When replying to a comment, please put @username of the person you reply to in the comment otherwise they don't get notified.  I stumbled across this reply by mistake).

Comment: I'm not suggesting there is a decrease in performance over time - I come from a Linux, not Windows background and way of thinking.  I'm suggesting that the FTP implementation may be slow and buggy.  Its possible the implementation is CPU bound, although I am sure the raw hardware can handle it if SMB works. Did it used to perform at the 100 megabit level for FTP?

Comment: Are you able to get a shell (eg SSH session) on the NAS?    If you can, maybe we can find some performance tools like vmstat, top and others which can help work out what the bottleneck is.   Most SOHO NAS's run Linux or BSD under the hood.  Not sure if this is relevant - https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/hx2751/terastation_ssh_access/

Comment: @davidgo Thanks. Linked tut didn't work but got me goin. I had success w/ acp_commander.jar in below repo. Im root over telnet. I ran `vmstat` and `top` while txing 500MB files. Screenshot added.
https://github.com/skx/Buffalo-220-NAS/blob/master/nas

I'm familiar with linux cli but not w/ extremely limited cli for getting details that may be pertinent to this issue. If you have more command suggestions, (like how to get FTP version mentioned before) lemme know.

P.s. Yes, I used to get better FTP speeds on device. I don't have benchmarks but def was not 2 wks for 500GB, was only hours.

Comment: Did you test the USB2.0 ports on that NAS? Sounds like they are quicker than SMB and FTP.

Comment: @Gantendo. I considered this however it's far from practical. I would either need to disconnect internal 3.5in HDD from desktop and buy a 3.5in HDD to USB adapter w/ external power source **or** transfer 500GB to portable drive. Then transfer from portable drive via USB to NAS. Honestly, I would rather set and forget @ 3MB/s than transfer across mediums twice and **trust** 100K files transferred perfectly both times w/o interruption.

Comment: MB/s and Mbps are not the same unit. 100 Mbps (networking speed of your NAS) = 12,5 MB/s including protocol overhead. That doesn't explain FTP performance, but SMB is already maxing it out.

Comment: @gronostaj I understand that megbytes and megabits are not the same. I edited the info in the post that caused confusion. While not explicitly stated, if FTP could transfer at rate of SMB, this would be acceptable and on par with expectations. Thanks.