# How do I move my Windows 10 Store apps to a specific folder on another drive?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I've tried following instructions here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/move-windows-10-apps-other-drive-change-install-location
but the problem is I only get to decide which partition to move the software to, no possibility to move the apps to a folder inside the partition.

So, how do I move them from there location to a specific folder inside a partition?

Comment: No; You can only decide which drive, limitations of the fact, the installation directory is protected by design

Comment: I strongly advise you not to do it at all. The move feature is already finicky. It broke those apps that I tried to move, forcing me to reset them.

Answer (score 0):

There is one possible way to deal with it - through creating a virtual hard disk.

Press Win+X, select Disk Management. In the "Action" menu above, click "Create VHD" and save it to some folder. Then initialize it and create a partition. At last you would be able to see the virtual drive appearing in the storage setting, and you are good to go.

Virtual hard disks are handled by Windows **System** itself so that's the difference.

For the below answer suggesting SMB: Yes you could also create and read a vhd through SMB. However I would strongly recommend that you get a new HDD, SSD or whatever directly. According to [my test between a Windows server and a Linux client over a 1GbE LAN](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/di8j1z/does_smbclient_on_linux_support_smb_v3/), the trassmission speed is only around 0.65 Gbps and it would be worse for fragmented files. I am doing this because I haven't got the money to buy a new HDD and the partition created for Windows 10 spared from a Ubuntu installation is too small to install something like Halo...

After all, if you **HAVE TO** connnect to the extra storage device through LAN, [configuring an iSCSI server](https://superuser.com/questions/148416/what-is-the-advantage-of-iscsi-over-smb) would be a better choice.

Answer (score -1):

Windows only allows to specify a drive as the new location,
maybe because it will create several new folders at that location.
However, there might be a way to trick Windows, by attributing a drive letter
to the folder.

Here is one way of doing that :

1. Open Windows Explorer, right click on the folder and choose Properties
2. In the Sharing tab, click Advanced sharing
3. Check "Share this folder", specify a name, then click OK
4. Still in Windows Explorer, open Network in left panel and click on your computer
5. Right-click on the new share and choose "Map network drive ..."
6. Choose a drive letter and check "Reconnect at sign-on"
7. Click OK

You may now try using the new "drive" for storing apps.
<sub>(As I have never done this, I do not guarantee success.)</sub>

Comment: Didn't work. Windows didn't list the newly mapped network drive. (Not that I am surprised. I actually know why.)

Comment: @FleetCommand: It worked for me on Windows 10, and should work equally on all other versions. Why not for you?

Comment: The Settings app does not see the drive letter in my case. That's a fact. (You may dispense with my speculations as to why it is so. But this is a cold hard fact.) And there is something else too: I don't feel comfy sharing my Store Apps over the network. Just FYI, Windows 10 v1607.

Comment: @FleetCommand: That's true - Settings does not see virtual disks! Before I delete this answer or write a new one, I would like to hear your speculations. (Comment for not sharing over the network - set the permissions appropriately.)